# Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0". in 000webhost

Tags: php, laravel

i uplaod my website on 000webhost , and change the php version on 000webhost from manage ebsite > website settings > general > change php version .. i choose 8.0 but not work , it shows the same error

Comment: _"i choose 8.0 but not work"_ - Well, the error says that your dependencies require version 8.1.0 or _higher_. Last time I looked, 8.0 was _lower_ than 8.1.

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` then try again

Answer (score 0):

000webhost does not support Laravel 9.x.
Currently, 000Webhost only supports PHP Version 8.0.0, so it cannot be accessed.